# Tags where all questions have been deleted still appear in tags listing

Tags: support, tags, deleted-questions, spam

On superuser.com, I saw a link to the tag [cybersex](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cybersex) in the [tags](https://superuser.com/tags) listing page (leading to the page title "Hottest 'cybersex' Questions). No questions are associated - presumably because it had been added through a spam question that was subsequently deleted. I would expect that in such a case (all questions associated with a specific tag have been deleted) that the tag itself would be deleted as well. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are periodic cleanup operations that will eventually eliminate unused tags.

Comment: I'm trying to find a source for this info, but you'll just have to believe me until I do ;-)

Comment: I think that the links give [in the tag-pruning tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) could count as a reasonable source. For tags with *no questions* specifically this one: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or “zombie”) tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753) (Although, looking at the timestamp, this is probably not that relevant now. But since I have stumbled upon the question, I have added the links.)