# What *currently* happens to zombie tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, faq-update-request

I've been doing some retagging on Super User lately, and the tag page still shows the old, crusty, now-orphaned tags.  Worse, [these](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/explain-to-newbie) [tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/beginners-guide) are [still available](https://superuser.com/posts/114375/revisions) via the tag autocompletion, reporting their pre-retagging tag counts.

I'm not expecting the retagging to immediately remove those orphans from the tag view, or update the tag counts.  I know these are done in batch *at some point*.  But the [FAQ on zombie tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags) indicates the tags are pruned hourly, and that's not my experience.

So, in order to update the FAQ, I'd like to know:

1. How frequently are zombie tags pruned?
2. How frequently are tag counts recalculated?

My goal with this is to ***a)*** know how the website is *supposed* to function, so I can report a bug if I need to; and ***b)*** update the FAQ with current information, to help future categorizers and tag editors know when their efforts will be reflected in the tag list.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The tag cleanup runs every 24 hours.

Comment: thanks!  straight from the horse's...er, unicorn's... mouth.

Comment: Neat! I always thought the zombie tags hung around to constantly irritate us re-taggers.