# Is there any process for getting rid of useless tags?

Tags: support, tags

A few minutes ago, I saw a tag called [am-i-missing-something](/questions/tagged/am-i-missing-something) on Stack Overflow. I assume someone asked a question using this tag, which was then deleted or edited, but this tag is still there.

I'm OK with it still existing, but to me, this tag doesn't make sense. I know there is a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) option, but this doesn't work for these kinds of tags.

What should be done in this situation? Is there an option like "vote to close this tag"?

Comment: `am-i-missing-something` = The coolest tag... ever :)

Comment: Sure it's not [tag:crap]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is — removing the tag. Unused tags will be [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags) after some time. For single-use tags like your example, you don't even technically *have* to do that, since they'll be deleted automatically too, but it can't hurt.

If a tag that you feel shouldn't exist has widespread usage, bring it up on the respective site's meta and it might just get [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/101417#101417) (or you might learn why it still exists).