# Remove misspelled tag from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What *currently* happens to zombie tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags)

How do I remove/request removal of a tag from Stack Overflow?

The tag [androind](/questions/tagged/androind) should probably be deleted; it appears to be a misspelling of 'android'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow (this site) is the correct place for requests like that.

For what it's worth, if there is a single question with such an incorrect tag, just correct it. Once the tag is no longer used for a question, it will eventually be deleted automatically. Your [androind](/questions/tagged/androind) example no longer has any questions attached to it, so it will be gone soon.

If there are many questions with a faulty/problematic tag, just bring it up here on Meta and the community can decide on the proper course of action.