# Burninate Tag [jquey]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

On SO I found a tag [jquey](/questions/tagged/jquey), that is I think a typo of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery). Currently this tag has no question associated with it. But as [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) is largely used tag, so SO user might use the wrong one as it looks same.

Comment: I think that's [the fourth duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huey,_Dewey,_and_Louie) of the apocalypse.

Comment: If it comes back, and it's apparent that this will be a recurring typo _despite_ auto completion of tags, we'll make a synonym to be sure it doesn't get in the system again.

Answer (score 10):

> Currently this tag has **no** questions associated  with it

Then it will be automatically removed [within the next 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags/40725#40725)