# Tag removal: Jqeury

Tags: support, tags

No, I'm not wanting you to remove [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), but there's a mis-spelt [jqeury](/questions/tagged/jqeury) that has cropped up. Can it be deleted? Currently, there are no questions that use the tag.

Comment: Tags with no questions are automatically cleaned up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to worry about a tag with zero question. Tag with zero questions get automatically clean on every 24 hours.

see [What *currently* happens to zombie tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/214722)

Answer (score 1):

Tags with no questions are automatically removed by the system probably in 24 hours.

Don't worry about it.

- [What *currently* happens to zombie tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags)
- [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)