# Misspelled new tag immediate deletion feature

Tags: feature-request, tags

There are lots of questions here about dealing with misspelled tags, yet none if them seem to offer a general non-moderator solution.

Recently, I noticed a new tag "quicksrot", which is obviously a misspelling of "quicksort", yet I was unable to delete, or request a deletion, of the new tag.

The closest similar action is to suggest a synonym, but as i lacked the reputation in the proper tag, i couldnt even do that. in any case, it is *not* a synonym; it is a misspelling.

The feature request is:

Offer a special action of "This is a misplacing of an existing tag" and the user (non-moderator) specifies which tag is the correctly spelled equivalent.

The suggestion is handled similarly to other edits regarding approval. Once approved, the misspelled tag is deleted and all usages replaced by the correct tag.

There could be additional prerequisites such as if the number of usages exceeds some threshold, it is also reviwed by a moderator before the corrective action is performed.

Comment: Just replace the misspelled tag with the actual one. If a tag has no questions, it will be automatically deleted in 24h.

Comment: Just to add on there's no need to go through and add wikis to the tag explaining that it's a mis-spelling. It actually gives it greater legitimacy and it will definitely be taken care of anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Yannis puts in the comment; you can edit the post and retag it with the correct one.

The older/mis-spelt tag, will then become a [zombie tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40724/212576). Such tags are deleted automatically every 24 hours.

Comment: +1 that Yannis fellow sounds smart ;)

Comment: It certainly seems so. :roll:

Comment: Turning the tag into a Zombie tag seems one way to do it then, but it would be simpler if you could zap it at the tag, rather than rely on a side-effect.

Comment: @Yannis Don't tell him that; it'll just go to his head.