# delete the [hello] tag

Tags: support, tags

I chanced across [the hello tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hello). It has no tag wiki and no questions. How/Should it be deleted?

More generally, how should I respond to a tag I find with no tag wiki and no questions tagged by it?

Comment: Don't worry , it will be automatically removed if not having any tagged questions.

Comment: Goodbye, hello.

Comment: hello? goodbye!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Lucifer notes, there's no need to take action to get rid of orphaned tags; they'll be automatically removed once a day.

From [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)

> Tags not associated with any question are pruned every 24 hours on the backend.