# Remove python-shapely tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I created the [python-shapely](/questions/tagged/python-shapely) tag last night as well as the [shapely](/questions/tagged/shapely) tag. I don't think there is any reason to have two tags, so I would like to have [python-shapely](/questions/tagged/python-shapely) deleted. It does not have any questions tagged.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shapely
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-shapely

Comment: Orphan tags get deleted automatically (once a day). Nothing needs to be done.

Comment: Related :[delete the hello tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152369/173001)

Comment: [What happens to Zombie tags ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/173001)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags are automatically deleted after 24 hours if there are no questions using them.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't know that.