# Unwanted Tag [manage]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[manage](/questions/tagged/manage) with no wiki summary exist on Stack Overflow, with 62 questions tagged. Some questions tagged with this, even not related to managed-code.

I think it should be removed (or renamed to [managed-code](/questions/tagged/managed-code)).

Comment: Don't rename it (especially since [tag:managed-code] already exists). The only use I can currently see for it is to help identify bad questions. Because there are a lot of those under that tag.

Answer (score 3):

I found one -- *one* -- question that was actually about managed/unmanaged code in the context of .net, and it has been retagged.

Most of the rest are demonstration of some users' complete and total inability to tag.  Some users, usually new users, think that tags are *keywords*, so they should stuff the tag list full of the same words that are in their question title or body.

The tag should be cleaned up, question by question.  Each question should be retagged and otherwise improved and/or vote-to-close'd.

Answer (score 3):

I just cleared all questions with the [manage](/questions/tagged/manage), put some of them into a better shape, removed tag lines, cast a few off-topic close votes.

There was [one (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969209/manage-a-team-of-programmers-who-are-in-different-states) that only had the <s>[manage](/questions/tagged/manage)</s> tag, I retagged it with [dcvs](/questions/tagged/dcvs) although the OP probably did not know about that.

**tl;dr**: [manage](/questions/tagged/manage) is gone.

Comment: it still exists, someone with the correct privileges needs to remove the tag

Comment: Wrong. [Tags will be removed at 3 am if there are no questions tagged with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/190161).

Comment: And it's now on my list of **105** tags I keep sleeping with the fishes.