# Accidentally created the [teaxx] tag

Tags: support, tags

I accidentally created an inaccurate tag on Stack Overflow - I created [teaxx](/questions/tagged/teaxx) when I should have been using [xxtea](/questions/tagged/xxtea).

How can I delete it, or get it deleted?

Comment: I think duplicate's a bit of a stretch for this... probably just related.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi so long as it serves as a signpost for future searchers it is ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Retag your question. It will be removed when the cleanup scripts run next, at 03:00 UTC to(day/night).

See [What happens to "zombie" tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags) for more info about tag deletion.