# Finding out why a particular tag was deleted

Tags: discussion, tags

How can one see why and when a particular tag was deleted and who did decided upon this?

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1104946

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tag wasn't deleted. All questions that were tagged, had the tag removed. The tag *will* be deleted soon, though - the [Great Orphan Reaper strikes once a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags).

I'm not aware of any way to discover the questions that most recently had the tag, other than the really hard, one-question-at-a-time way. You might get lucky if Google/DDG/Bing hasn't indexed the question since the tag was removed, or you might search for questions that would have had the tag at one point.

Comment: Pity that they cannot be revived, only re-created :-/

Comment: @Arioch'The If you can find those that did most of the burnination, you could look through their revision history for the posts that used to be tagged with the tag.