# Remove or retag [kepler] and [indigo] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are tags such as [[kepler]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) and [[indigo]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indigo) which clearly seem to be eclipse versions and there are already tags for them [[eclipse-kepler]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-kepler).

There are no users who have starred these tags and neither are there any questions posted under it. Shouldn't they be marked as synonyms or deleted?

Answer (score 2):

There are no questions that use either these tags.

[Tags with no questions are automatically deleted after a certain period of time has elapsed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags).

No action is required.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. Will keep that in mind. :)