# What should I do for wrong spelled tag

Tags: support, tags, spelling

If I found a wrong spelled tag , what should I do ?
[Javscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javscript) ? I think it's JAVASCRIPT .
Can I flag to moderator for it ?

Comment: Burninate.. 0 questions..

Comment: There are no questions with that tag. It effectively does not exist. Within 24 hours, it won't have ever existed.

Comment: Smetimes peope mis a few keys whn taging. Jus edt to fix an it wil sove itelf in 24 hurs.

Comment: tank yu vry muh Tm Pot :)

Comment: Would it be an abuse of flags if I were to flag your comment as offensive @TimPost? Grrrr

Comment: Would it be an abuse of flags if I were to flag your comment as Scare me ? :O

Answer (score 4):

If any question is tagged with that tag just retag it with the correct one. It will be deleted automatically within [24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/187824).