# Delete `visual-stuido` tag or merge it with `visual-studio`

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-deletion

Because of the typo, I'd like to suggest the [visual-stuido](/questions/tagged/visual-stuido) tag be deleted or merged with [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio). On Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need. There are no questions tagged with [visual-stuido](/questions/tagged/visual-stuido). Someone must've gone through and retagged today. Tags without questions are [pruned every day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags).

Comment: Yes, [thank you Charles](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18409959/revisions)!