# How do I flag a tag, If it is not constructive

Tags: discussion, tags

How can I delete or flag a tag to moderator, when it is not constructive. This [**tag**](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) is not useful for drupal answers. So my question is how to remove this tag ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a tag should not be around, simply remove the tag by editing, or by suggesting an edit. Once a tag has no questions associated to it, it [will disappear within 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). A moderator does not need to be involved.

If there are a fair few questions with the tag, take the issue to [the site's Meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/). There you can discuss if the tag should be around, and how to approach the cleanup once consensus has been reached.

Comment: You kind of make it sound like you can freely remove any tag that doesn't have too many questions if you think it shouldn't be there. IMO it would be better to raise a Meta discussion for even the smallest tags, especially if you're not a high-rep user.

Comment: If there is any doubt, sure, take it to the appropriate Meta @Dukeling. But not every single-question tag needs an extensive discussion. And for <2k users it would be a suggested edit anyway, which will see it reviewed by 5 users. I don't think there's a lot of danger there.

Comment: That should of course have read "reviewed by 3 to 5 users"