# How to report a bad tag which was used in a question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I found a tag named [decoactor](/questions/tagged/decoactor). As this tag is only used in one question and there are no
followers I assume that it was an incorrect tag. Taken the discussion about Zombie tags only 
tags without associated questions are erased ([How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)).

How can I report/delete a tag which was used once but is a zombie?

Comment: Edit the post, correct the tag. Since only *that* post used the tag, it will get deleted after 24 hours (I guess, don't know the perfect time)

Comment: I just removed the tag. It will be deleted in 24 hours as @AshishNitinPatil said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I said in [my comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211661/how-to-report-a-bad-tag-which-was-used-in-a-question#comment680699_211661), [JoshC removed the tag from the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20594193/2). Given that the tag is no longer used in *any* question, it will be deleted at 03:00 UTC.

Answer (score 6):

If it's just misspelled, edit the question and remove/rename the tag, and it will be removed. All tags with no questions will be cleared out by an automatic script that runs once a day, so it'll be gone today or tomorrow.