# Why does the Javacript tag exist?

Tags: discussion, tags

I found a silly tag.  It's called [javacript](/questions/tagged/javacript)

The description is `WRONG TAG! Use [javascript] instead!`.  So why does this tag still exist?  Can tags be deleted?  Will this tag *ever* be deleted?  I think it's useless, and just taking up space.

We don't need it.  So why do we want it?  *Do* we want it, or just no mods have seen it (can mods delete tags)?

I think the person who made this tag was just creating spam.  Even if you mistype [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), it's easily accessible in the [main tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page.  Mods or the admins or *someone* should be able to see who makes these tags, because for the people who are *trusted* who can *make tags* might make more **mistakes** like this, and probably be restricted from tag creating for maybe a day?  Does anyone agree?

[EDIT]

I just realized from the answers that tags *do indeed* get deleted if they don't have any questions within 24 hours.  Thanks for the information!  I will read more (for those interested, it has a question at [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) - thanks **DoorknobOfSnow**).

[EDIT TO THE EDIT]

I just again realized that there are *many* zombie tags, such as [textbo](/questions/tagged/textbo).  But they will all be deleted as shown in the answer to [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags).

PS.

If everyone is wondering why those tag links are broken (not yet), it's probably because they are now deleted (because they are zombie tags).

Comment: Yeah, let's delete it. In general, tags that exist due to a misspelling shouldn't exist.

Comment: The Java CryptKeeper is going to be really upset that someone misspelled the name of his hangout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are currently no questions tagged with it, meaning it's a "zombie tag." The system [automatically deletes these with a script that runs once every day at 3:00 AM or so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/180276) (UTC).

I'm not sure your last paragraph makes much sense. Tags get created by accident, humans are not infallible, we do make typos occasionally. Would you want to be completely banned from a privilege just because you made a tiny one-character typo? Does it really matter anyway?

Comment: Can you please provide the *page* that says this so I can read more?  Also, I don't think you can mistype *Javascript* with it being on the main tag page and all

Comment: @ManofSnow http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/180276

Comment: I didn't recall the link in your answer :) also, re-stating, my question states that the Javascript tag is about the 3rd tag, how can someone try to re-create it?

Comment: @ManofSnow Umm... the 3rd what? I'm not sure what you're trying to say

Comment: If you go [here,](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) it's the 3rd tag shown.  It's pretty hard to miss that, and I'm sure stackoverflow tells the people who are making tags would check if it already exist

Comment: @ManofSnow No, [javascript] is the third most commonly used tag. I don't see [javacript] anywhere there...

Comment: I see it, in a blue box.  How can someone go to the tags page without seeing Javascript blue in a box?

Comment: @ManofSnow Could you post a screenshot? [javacript] has no questions tagged with it, so why would it appear on the first page?

Comment: Not Javacript, Javascript.  The person who created Javacript was obviously trying to create a Javascript tag, and didn't look to see if it existed first

Comment: @ManofSnow People make typos... are you saying that you're perfect and never make a mistake?

Comment: Are you saying tags are automatically created when people include them in their questions?  In that case, I didn't know

Comment: @ManofSnow ...as opposed to new tags just being removed? What else would you expect?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it through

Answer (score 2):

Since this tag has no questions using it, it will be auto deleted at 3:00 UTC tomorrow, as a scheduled task auto deletes tags with no questions in them at that time.

Answer (score 2):

> Will this tag ever be deleted?

The tag has no questions, so it will be deleted within 24 hours.

> can mods delete tags?

Yes, they can. There have already been some requests on MSO to delete a tag, they are tagged with the [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag.