# Why did Community just create an unused tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Community just created a tag on Stackoverflow called `javscript`.

There are no questions, on Stackoverflow, with this tag.

It appears to be a mispelling of javascript.

Why was it created?

[image: javscript tag - created by community 10 minutes ago]

Comment: No, a *tag wiki* was created, because someone (e.g. an actual person) used a misspelled tag. The tag and wiki will be cleaned up automatically. Community only gets the blame because there is no actual user account to create tag wikis.

Comment: thx @MartijnPieters

Comment: Presumably you found the revision because of that tag wiki edit; you were correct in rejecting it. If it is any consolation, when the tag wiki is deleted, the 2 points the user got for their efforts is also revoked.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. thx

Comment: That edit is particularly useless because tags with no questions attached are not even listed for auto-completion. Noone will see that tag wiki, normally.

Comment: So how did that user find it? Just looking through the tags?

Comment: It could be they were the one that corrected the tag. You can still find it in the [tags page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) if you search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused the tag wiki history with the tag itself.

Someone accidentally created the tag `javscript`; it'll be cleaned up automatically as there are no posts associated (see [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags)).

Then someone [suggested a useless tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4592793) for that tag; for that to work an initial revision is needed, so the *system* creates that initial revision in the database and needs to attach a user account to it. The edit suggestion triggered this but there is no point in attaching their name to that revision, so Community gets the blame instead. You'll notice that the timestamp on the initial revision matches the timestamp on the suggested edit exactly.

The tag wiki will be deleted together with the tag, come tomorrow this'll all be gone again.

Comment: One moment, I need to go punch some reviewers in the face...

Comment: @animuson: Please do! That was a *very useless* wiki edit and should never have been approved.

Comment: They've all been review banned for a day with a nice message. ;P Letting moderators enter a message makes that review ban option so much more useful.

Comment: The wiki edit was perhaps not _that_ bad: `"Do not use this tag. Use [Javascript] instead."`